# Polymorphism in Swing

Tags: java, polymorphism

I basically do all my desktop projects using swing, and I discovered WindowBuilder, which is awesome. But I use polymorphism to create a window model for many window that I create, and it seems like that WindowBuilder doesn't like it (it doesn't recognize a window that extends another). So i want to know: does using polymorphism alongside swing work better than creating single, independent windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism can be very powerful and useful in Swing, as it can be across OO programming in general. It can also sometimes make more of a mess of things than it's worth in Swing, as it can across OO programming in general.

In Swing, like anywhere else, what matters is how you reason through your usage of polymorphism: Where it's reasonable, theres *nothing* inherent about Swing that makes it more difficult to implement than it is anywhere else.

I don't know anything about WindowBuilder, but if it's keeping you from reasoning about your usage of polymorphism, or otherwise limiting or influencing your thought about other architectural decisions, *then the tool is probably not as great as you think it is*, and is almost certainly not worth that cost. No tool is.

Comment: So, polymorphism is a question of preference?

Comment: @gcarvalho97: no, it's a question of the best tool for the job at hand. Most coders I know prefer composition to inheritance, but don't shy away from inheritance in situations that benefit greatly by its use. Improper use of polymorphism, such as to "share" variables, will fail, and over-use, such as to extend complex classes that don't need extending, can be dangerous. Witness what happens with Swing programs when you extend a JComponent of some kind, and then give it an x and y field complete with getters and setters -- disaster.  1+ to this answer.

Comment: @gcarvalho97: *Everything* is a matter of preference - or, more accurately: *Every* decision you make should be made because *you* reasoned through it and decided it was best. You'll find no shortage of "best practices" regarding most any topic you'll ever encounter, and you should consider them carefully - but with very few exceptions, they're all just rules of thumb: *What is best in each particular use case is up to the programmer doing the coding* Making those decisions is the job of programming :)

Comment: @gcarvalho97 - note that, while Hovercraft and I gave different one-word answers, those two comments are telling you the same thing.